# Put Lists With Title in List

Tags: android, xml, list, android-layout

I have A Search Page For My App:

Search is in 3 part:

- musics
- albums
- artists

I Put Each Part In A List. but when user scroll In Musics, albums and Artists Are Fix (For Artist and Albums is same).

xml code:

```xml
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MusicResultTitle"
        android:text="@string/musics"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <com.takusemba.multisnaprecyclerview.MultiSnapRecyclerView
            app:msrv_snap_count="4"
            app:msrv_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MusicsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
            android:layout_below="@id/MusicResultTitle" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/AlbumResultTitle"
            android:text="@string/albums"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/MusicsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <com.takusemba.multisnaprecyclerview.MultiSnapRecyclerView
            app:msrv_snap_count="4"
            app:msrv_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/AlbumsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
            android:layout_below="@id/AlbumResultTitle" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ArtistResultTitle"
            android:text="@string/artists"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/AlbumsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <com.takusemba.multisnaprecyclerview.MultiSnapRecyclerView
            app:msrv_snap_count="4"
            app:msrv_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ArtistsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
            android:layout_below="@id/ArtistResultTitle" />
```

I Want TO put 3 part in one list like this:

Musics:

- music1
- music2
- music3

Albums:

- album1
- album2
- album3

Artists:

- artist1
- artist2
- artist3

**And In Scroll All Of theme Move**.

Comment: Use NestedScrollView for smooth scroll if you're using recyclerview inside the ScrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them inside a scrollview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MusicResultTitle"
        android:text="@string/musics"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <com.takusemba.multisnaprecyclerview.MultiSnapRecyclerView
        app:msrv_snap_count="4"
        app:msrv_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MusicsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@id/MusicResultTitle" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AlbumResultTitle"
        android:text="@string/albums"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/MusicsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <com.takusemba.multisnaprecyclerview.MultiSnapRecyclerView
        app:msrv_snap_count="4"
        app:msrv_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AlbumsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@id/AlbumResultTitle" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ArtistResultTitle"
        android:text="@string/artists"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/AlbumsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <com.takusemba.multisnaprecyclerview.MultiSnapRecyclerView
        app:msrv_snap_count="4"
        app:msrv_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ArtistsMultiSnapRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@id/ArtistResultTitle" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```